# get a classes property-names given only the class-name

Tags: c#

I want to know the names of all the properties of a class, given only the classes name.
It should look something like this:

```
public object GetClassAttribute(string className)
```

### Example:

Given these two classes:

```
public class PersonItem
    {
       public string Name {get;set;}
       public string LastName   {get;set;}
       public byte Age   {get;set;}
    }

public class DepartmentItem
        {
           public string DepartmentName {get;set;}
           public string Office  {get;set;}
           public string Address   {get;set;}
        }
```

The function should give something like this:

```
var ListAttribute= GetClassAttribute(Person);

// returns:
// ListAttribute[0] "Name"
// ListAttribute[1] "LastName"
// ListAttribute[2] "Age

var ListAttribute= GetClassAttribute(DepartmentItem);
// returns:
// ListAttribute[0] "DepartmentName "
// ListAttribute[1] "Office  "
// ListAttribute[2] "Address
```

Comment: I cannot see a dynamic class here

Comment: Do you mean Person is dynamic object?? Where is dynamic here..

Comment: dynamically changing class name

Comment: So you need convert a string either an xml or json to object and get values from those?? in this method "public object GetClassAttribute(string className)"

Comment: I think König's answer is exactly what he wants.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to reflect over a type. What you asked can be queried like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> FieldsOf(string className)
{
    var asm = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
    var type = asm.GetTypes().Single(t => t.Name == className);
    var fields = type.GetFields();
    return fields.Select(f => f.Name);
}
```

This function first gets it's calling assembly and then searchs for a unique class having the given name - you have to do this because normaly you would search by full-name (including it's namespace) using `Assembly.GetType(fullName)` but the example you gave did not.
This one can fail if you have multiple classes with the same name (for example different namespaces)!

Finally it gets all fields and returns their names.
This will not find the properties too! (You have to search them with `GetProperties`) and you will propably want to controll the way the fields are found too - for example no privates, etc. all this can be controlled by checking the fields properties or by giving more parameters to `GetFields`.

BTW: your class - definition is wrong too - there are `;` missing after each line:

```
public class PersonItem
{
    public string Name;
    public string LastName;
    public byte Age;
}
```

You can print it's fields like this:

```
foreach (var f in FieldsOf("PersonItem"))
    Console.WriteLine(f);
```

### Getting the value of those fields for an instance too:

I guess sooner or later you need the values too - here is an extension to the method above that shows how you could do this too:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, Func<object, object>>> FieldsOf(string className)
{
    var asm = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
    var type = asm.GetTypes().Single(t => t.Name == className);
    var fields = type.GetFields();

    return fields.Select(f => Tuple.Create<string, Func<object, object>>(f.Name, f.GetValue));
}
```

This one returns the `Name` and the `Getter` of the field in a tuple (enough for this example - normaly you should use a struct or something with better names than `Item1` and `Item2` on it's properties).

Here is an example:

```
Object person = new PersonItem {Name = "John", LastName = "Smith", Age = 33};

foreach (var f in FieldsOf("PersonItem"))
    Console.WriteLine("Fieldname: {0} - Value: {1}", f.Item1, f.Item2(person));
```

This will give this output:

```
Fieldname: Name - Value: John
Fieldname: LastName - Value: Smith
Fieldname: Age - Value: 33
```

### Include properties

As you now changed you question so that the class you use only has properties (not fields) - you need to include those too:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, Func<object, object>>> FieldsOf(string className)
    {
        var asm = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
        var type = asm.GetTypes().Single(t => t.Name == className);
        var fields = type.GetFields();
        var properties = type.GetProperties();

        return 
            fields.Select(f => Tuple.Create<string, Func<object, object>>(f.Name, f.GetValue))
            .Concat(properties.Select(p => Tuple.Create<string, Func<object, object>>(p.Name, o => p.GetValue(o, null))));
    }
```

*Note:* this code will only get properties not using indexes (as you have given) - this is the part `o => p.GetValue(o, null)` - the `null` is where the indexes needs to go if you also need those.

### Using `Type` instead of type-name

Amir made a good point: you can use the types too.

This one is good if you don't know the objects type at compile-time:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, Func<object, object>>> FieldsOf(Type type)
{
    var fields = type.GetFields();
    var properties = type.GetProperties();

    return
        fields.Select(f => Tuple.Create<string, Func<object, object>>(f.Name, f.GetValue))
        .Concat(properties.Select(p => Tuple.Create<string, Func<object, object>>(p.Name, o => p.GetValue(o, null))));
}
```

Example:

```
Object person = new PersonItem {Name = "John", LastName = "Smith", Age = 33};

foreach (var f in FieldsOf(person.GetType()))
    Console.WriteLine("Fieldname: {0} - Value: {1}", f.Item1, f.Item2(person));

Console.ReadLine();
```

### Using generics instead of type-name

Here is a generic version - this one is good if you know the type at compile time:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, Func<T, object>>> FieldsOf<T>()
{
    var type = typeof (T);
    var fields = type.GetFields();
    var properties = type.GetProperties();

    return
        fields.Select(f => Tuple.Create<string, Func<T, object>>(f.Name, o => f.GetValue(o)))
        .Concat(properties.Select(p => Tuple.Create<string, Func<T, object>>(p.Name, o => p.GetValue((T)o, null))));
}
```

Example:

```
var person = new PersonItem {Name = "John", LastName = "Smith", Age = 33};

foreach (var f in FieldsOf<PersonItem>())
    Console.WriteLine("Fieldname: {0} - Value: {1}", f.Item1, f.Item2(person));

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

The two answers above are great, but your asking a specific question for properties so here's a "copy paste" answer:

```
    public IEnumerable<string> GetPropertyNames(Type type)
    {
        return type.GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name);
    }
```

Usage:

```
   var personItemProps = GetPropertyNames(typeof(PersonItem)).ToList();
   var departmentItemProps = GetPropertyNames(typeof(DepartmentItem)).ToList();
```

You can also do this with an extension function on "Type":

```
    public static class TypeExtensions
    {
       public static IEnumerable<string> GetPropertyNames(this Type type)
       {
           return type.GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name);
       }
    }
```

Usage:

```
    var personItemProps = typeof(PersonItem).GetPropertyNames().ToList();
    var departmentItemProps = typeof(DepartmentItem).GetPropertyNames().ToList();
```

If you dont need IEnumerables, then just change the function to return a List instead.

Comment: good point - maybe he don't need it by string (and by type is nicer)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of attribute from class name (string), first convert the string to Type using Type.GetType. Once you have the type you can call GetFields() to get the properties.

*Method definition*

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetClassAttribute(string className)
{
    Type t = Type.GetType(className);
    return t.GetFields().Select(f=>f.Name);
}
```

*Method call*

```
var attributes = GetClassAttribute("ClassNamespace.PersonItem");
```

**Note** You will need to provide namespace with your class as stated in MSDN documentation given as under.

[Type GetType(string typeName)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> typeName Type: System.String The assembly-qualified name of the type
>   to get. See AssemblyQualifiedName. If the type is in the currently
>   executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the
>   type name qualified by its namespace.